# No line number when cursor is at the end of a long line

Tags: emacs, spacemacs

As [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2u1WZ.jpg) picture shows, the line numbers is gone when I move to the end of the line. Is there a way to keep the line numbers? Its kinda inconvenient isn't?

Here's another [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xD0Sz.jpg) showing the line numbers.

Comment: You are using long lines that extend beyond the width of the window, and `truncate-lines` is set to `t`. This has absolutely *nothing* to do with **spacemacs**. If you want to see the left fringe with line numbers and have `truncate-lines` set to `t`, then you'll need to be on a location that is farther to the left. Sorry, but there is no solution unless you (or someone else) wants to spend time creating a new package for placing line-numbers in a different location besides inside the left fringe. Alternatively, set `truncate-lines` to `nil` and let the long lines wrap at the right edge.

Comment: @lawlist as someone just switched from vim, i cant help comparing emacs with vim all the time. I wonder why its implemented this way in emacs. As in vim, the line number is always there no matter where your location is.

Comment: In playing with the C-source code (redisplay) several months ago, the only built-in support for calculating the line number that I saw related to the mode-line -- i.e., so that the user can display the current line number in the mode-line if so desired.  From what I gather, Emacs was never designed internally to display line numbers on each line of a visible window.  The built-in Lisp library `linum.el` is frowned upon by Eli Z. (the right-hand man of the maintainer John W.) for a variety of reasons, and the library `nlinum.el` by Stefan is preferred.  Emacs line numbering is an after-thought.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in `linum-mode` (and `nlinum-mode` which seems to suffer from the same problem).  I recommend you `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Comment: @shangsunset -- since Stefan is the author of `nlinum` and he is *perhaps* offering to implement this new feature (or to fix a bug), I would definitely recommend jumping on the invitation!  :)  I would love to see how the new feature (or bug fix) is ultimately implemented).  Eli Z. will not likely help fix anything relating to `linum.el` -- he hates it with a passion because it abuses the `post-command-hook`, and a variety of other reasons.